# after checking some condition inside render() want to update state value using setState, how can I do that?

Tags: reactjs, render, setstate

I guess writing setState() inside render() leads to infinite call of the render(), but I have to update the condition in the similar way.

here is my mock code.

```
export default class MapSeat extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data: props.data
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    this.setState({ data: nextProps.data });
  }

render(){
    const { data } = this.state;
    const { parameter1, parameter2} = data;

    return (
          <SomeComponent
            persons={data.persons}
            onPersonSelect={(f) => {
              let person = find(data.persons, function (o) { return o.id === f; });

              this.setState({
                data: {
                  parameter1: person.fullName,
                  parameter2: person.id
                }
              });
              this.setState({ data: this.state.data });
            }}/>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your handler method in Component body.

```
personSelectHandler(f){
 let data = // You need to get data from somewhere of course.
 let person = find(data.persons, function (o) { return o.id === f; });

          this.setState({
            data: {
              parameter1: person.fullName,
              parameter2: person.id
            }
          });
          this.setState({ data: this.state.data });
}
```

Then reference it from render() like so :

```
render(){

 return (
      <SomeComponent
        persons={data.persons}
        onPersonSelect={this.personSelectHandler} />
 );
}
```

Finally, in `<SomeComponent />` you can call it as :

```
handler(){
  let f = //your param to send parent
  this.props.onPersonSelect(f);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is :

1) Define the callback function, in your case:

```
(f) => {
          let person = find(data.persons, function (o) { return o.id === f; });

          this.setState({
            data: {
              parameter1: person.fullName,
              parameter2: person.id
            }
          });
          this.setState({ data: this.state.data });
        }
```

as a separate function inside the mapSeat component.(Let's just call this function 'foo' for simplicity)

2) Bind that function to the map seat component constructor:

```
this.foo = this.foo.bind(this);
```

3) Pass the reference of the function you defined in step 2 as props while invoking the component:

```
<SomeComponent
        persons={data.persons}
        onPersonSelect={this.foo}/>
```

4) Finally in your new component (i.e. SomeComponent). Just call that function in the following way whenever the callback function is needed:

```
this.props.foo();
```

Because of step 2, the function will be bound to the context of the parent component. And thus, will be able to modify the state of the parent component even when it's called from the child component.

**Note: This will trigger the render() method of the parent and by extension the child component.**

Hope this helps! :)